# Keep UIButton at bottom of viewController and in front of TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, button

I'm trying to set a `UIButton` at the bottom of my `viewController` in front of my `TableView`.

I succeeded, the button is under the TableView but is only visible when I scroll down to the end of the table view.

I want it to be visible at all times, even when the scorll is up.

This is my code cheho tried to do:

```
var button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
button.frame = CGRectMake(00, 100, self.view.bounds.size.width, 50)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
button.setTitle("View", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: "Action:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(button)
self.tableView.tableFooterView = button;
```

Comment: The Button should be over your UITableView (the scroll Area) - or under, so you have not a Fullscreen UITable?

Comment: you want the UIButton you stick to the bottom of your screen?

Comment: Under the TableView, because I have to have a button always visible needs to do an action when the user selects what to see in the TableView

Comment: @YuviGr yes bottom of  screen

Comment: add UIView bottom of the view. To that add ur button.

Answer (score 1):

***Edit***

I found another solution :

```
var button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    button.frame = CGRectMake(00, 100, self.view.bounds.size.width, 50)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    button.setTitle("View", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "Action:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    var frame:CGRect=button.frame
    frame.origin.y=scrollView.contentOffset.y+100
    self.button.frame=frame
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(button)

}
```

This should help :)

Comment: Just edited. It should work now :) .If it did please upvote and tick the answer :)

Comment: Let me explain: I wrote your code. when I make the scroll button remains firm at the top down.

Comment: I just added 100 to `scrollView.contentOffset.y` as your y-coordinate for the button is 100

Comment: mm no this is not very recommended. However, even if I enter manually position the last cell of TableView when I flow to the bottom is not seen.

Comment: Hmm.. As far as I can make out from your comment, you cant see it when you're at the last cell? Or you always want it to be at the bottom?

Comment: You always want to see that even in the depths. A possible solution could be to increase the size of the content Table View. This should work. It remains however the problem of positioning the button below in an automatic way. You can not know the value that you have entered (100) automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in cellforrow method of tableview.

```
- `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
{

    for(UIView *v in [cell.contentView subviews])
        {
            [v removeFromSuperview];
        }

}
```

and instead of addsubview use this.

```
[self.view.contentView addSubview:button];
```